# Google Nest display issue when there are duplicate response

Tags: actions-on-google

I created a google action using Google action SDK web hook. When there are same responses in a row, the first message moves all the way to the top of the window, higher than normal display window. In certain Nest version, it even holds up the conversation.

Comment: is it one request with multiple responses that have the same message or are they two separate requests that sent back the same message? Please share a screenshot of that message. That'll help as well.

When you said "it even holds up the conversation", can you further elaborate on what it means?

Comment: It happens when there are two separate requests that sent back with the same message. It holds up means the conversation is stuck, no response. After a few seconds, the conversation ends.